# IBM MQ connectivity is failing

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

We are trying to connect to IBM MQ using certificates in a Spring Boot app, but we are getting following error while connectivity only in production environment:

```
JMSCMQ0001:IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
```

We are able to connect to MQ in all other lower environments with the same config.

Comment: You need to look at the queue manger's `AMQERR01.LOG` to determine the cause.  2035 can be returned to the client due to CHLAUTH blocking the connection, permissions error,  a MCAUSER that is not valid,  if user ID and password are being checked by CONNAUTH and fail it also causes 2035.

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM website](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/2035-mqrcnotauthorized-wmq) indicates what the problem is caused by:

> MQRC 2035 (MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED) is returned when a user is not authorized to perform the function that is attempted.

To resolve the issue:

> Determine which object the user cannot access and provide the user access to the object.

The IBM website details a few ways to debug the issue further.